# unit testing in tornado

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I'm building a simple web application in tornado.web using mongodb as the backend. 90% of the server-side codebase lives in a set of RequestHandlers, and 90% of the data objects are json.  As a result, the basic use case for testing handlers is:

```
"Given Request Y and DB in state X,
 verify that handler method Z returns json object J"
```

How do I set up this kind of test?

I've found a few blog posts and discussion threads on the topic, but they mainly focus on setting up asyncronous.  I can't find anything on setting up the right kind of DB state or GET/POST request arguments.

- http://emptysquare.net/blog/tornado-unittesting-eventually-correct/
- http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/testing.html
- https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/867cfb2665ea10a9/319555e619fe6c5c

Comment: Let's start bounty. I'm interested in this question also.

Comment: I asked a few tornado developers this question offline, and the answer they gave me was "It's very hard."

Comment: A better answer might be "use fat models and skinny controllers."  Controllers are hard to unit test, but if the validation and object manipulation logic lives in models, we can test it anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would typically mock out the inputs and just test the output. This is a contrived example using this mocking library - http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/. You would have to mock out the correct mongodb query function. I'm not sure what you are using.

```
from mock import Mock, patch
import json


@patch('my_tornado_server.mongo_db_connection.query')
def test_a_random_handler_returns_some_json(self, mock_mongo_query):

    request = Mock()
    # Set any other attributes on the request that you need
    mock_mongo_query.return_value = ['pink', 'orange', 'purple']

    application = Mock()
    handler = RandomHandler(application, request)
    handler.write = Mock()

    handler.get('some_arg')

    self.assertEqual(handler.write.call_args_list, json.dumps({'some': 'data'}))
```

Comment: Problem of Mocks is that if we have to change db schema / storage - we have to change all mocks.

Comment: Not if the return value of the mock is derived from wherever you define your db schema.

Comment: Ou I see, in this case we are not testing data, that will be actually returned by mongo.

Comment: Well you must call a function that tells you the state of the db. You mock out the return value of that function, and you derive the format of that return value from the db schema.

Comment: Perhaps what you are really asking for is help with integration or functional testing? It doesn't sound like these are really unit tests. If so I would suggest Selenium and Webdriver. Very easy to use

Comment: I'm asking for help with unit testing, and for me great example is how they done in django. When test database created before test suite run and dropped after.

Comment: By the way, your answer is useful. :)

Comment: Haha, thanks Nikolay. I should hope so. I work with a group of guys that all do TDD and we use Tornado a lot.